# Long If statement refactoring - java

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

I have "long" if statements in for loop.

What It trying to do is tokenize a line.

For example,

Ex1) Tokenize this line `"class Main {"` into a ArrayList `[ 'class' , 'Main', '{' ]`

Ex2) `let length = Keyboard.readInt("HOW MANY NUMBERS? ");` (In this line String in quotation mark is a one token)

-> `['let', 'length', '=', 'Keyboard', '.', 'readInt', '(', '"HOW MANY NUMBERS? "', ')' ';']`

There are 8 different conditions which are logic of tokenization. And each condition has different action to tokenize line.

The overall logic is like this

```
for ( char c : line ){
    if (condition){
        doSomething1(); //like arrayList.add(c)
        doSomething2(); //like tempWord += c
    }else if(condition2) {
        doSomething2();
    }else if(condition3) {
        doSomething2();
        doSomething3();
    }
```

I functionized each conditions

```
   private static boolean isOpeningQuotationMark(char currentChar) {
        return (currentChar == '\"' && progressInQuotationMark == false);
    }

   private static boolean isClosingQuotationMark(char currentChar) {
        return (currentChar == '\"' && progressInQuotationMark == true);
    }
    ...
   private static boolean metSymbolAtFull(char currentChar) {
        return Symbol.contains(currentChar) && !tempWord.isEmpty();
    }
```

And real code is here

```
public static ArrayList<String> tokenize(String line){
        ArrayList<String> tokenizedLine = new ArrayList<>();

        for (char currentChar : line.toCharArray()) {
            if (isOpeningQuotationMark(currentChar)) {
                progressInQuotationMark = true;
            } else if (isClosingQuotationMark(currentChar)) {
                tokenizedLine.add('\"' + tempWord + '\"');
                tempWord = "";
                progressInQuotationMark = false;
            } else if (progressInQuotationMark) {
                tempWord += currentChar;
            } else if (isTailWhiteSpace(currentChar)) {
                tokenizedLine.add(tempWord);
                tempWord = "";
            } else if (isHeadWhiteSpace(currentChar)) {
                ;
            } else if (!isSymbol(currentChar)) {
                tempWord += currentChar;
            } else if (metSymbolAtFull(currentChar)) {
                tokenizedLine.add(tempWord);
                tokenizedLine.add(String.valueOf(currentChar));
                tempWord = "";
            } else if (metSymbolAtEmpty(currentChar)) {
                tokenizedLine.add(String.valueOf(currentChar));
                tempWord = "";
            }
        }
        return tokenizedLine;
    }
```

This code works fine. But I think there are code smells.
Because

1. "long" if statement.
2. I think it violates Open Closed Principle.
3. The order of if statement is hard to change.
4. If I want to change or add new condition, I have to think all the conditions again.

What I tried is

1. make a new class for a char in lines. `class CodeChar` . But This Class needed a tempWord of original logic and some conditions in caller class.
2. I made a enum for each conditions and made them type attribute of CodeChar.
   So I can make `Set` dictionary of `<CodeCharType, Runnable>` <- Runnable in this Set is logic inside if statements

But Those also caused dependency of each other and looks kinda "dirty"

How can I solve this problem? Is there a pattern for this?

Before I consider changing the if statement, Are There already fundamental design problem?

Or Is that okay to be like that?

Comment: hello and welcome to SO. Please ask only one specific question at a time, and for code smells just read the book "Clean Code" it has pretty much everything anyone needs to know.

Comment: if I understand your question correctly, this is better suited on a site for code review. Try here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're basically building a lexer/parser from scratch, there's been *tons* of content written on possible ways to implement them and their pros/cons. I suggest you use those terms to do some basic investigation on your own and then come back with a more concrete question, if you still have them.

Comment: You should not copy contents of the already existing `String` to a `tempWord`, even less by repeated `+=` operations. Remember *positions* within the string. Use methods like [`regionMatches`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches(int,java.lang.String,int,int)) to check whether you are looking at a known sequence and `substring` if you really need the part as a new `String`. Or learn to use regex [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and `Matcher`.